# Multiplicity of zeros using derivatives

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Can I find multiplicity of zeros of a polynomial function using its derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(r) = f'(r) = \ldots = f^{(k)}(r) = 0$ but $f^{(k+1)}(r) \ne 0$, then $r$ is a root of multiplicity $k+1$.

Comment: Thank you sir..